# What do input and output chains in NAT table do?

Tags: linux, iptables

I understand what `prerouting` and `postrouting` chains do in IPTables, but I cannot understand what do `output` and `input` chains do.
So in NATing, we change the destination IP or port using `DNAT` in `prerouting`, or the source IP to get the reply to the correct interface using `SNAT` or `MASQURADE` in `postrouting`.

In this scenario I find no usage to `input` and `output` chains. Could someone explain them (`input` and `output`) quickly to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains are traversed for packets delivered to and sent from applications running on the local machine.

If an application sends out a packet, it traverses

```
app -> OUTPUT -> POSTROUTING -> interface
```

Conversely, a packet delivered to an application traverses

```
interface -> PREROUTING -> INPUT -> app
```

While a forwarded packet traverses

```
interface -> PREROUTING -> FORWARD -> POSTROUTING -> interface
```

Note that `MASQUERADE` is just a special case of `SNAT`, where the source address is taken from the interface.

Also see [this picture](http://developer.gauner.org/doc/iptables/images/nfk-traversal.png) or many similar ones you can find in `iptables` tutorials.

**Edit**

If you want to do `DNAT` for packets sent from an application, you must use `OUTPUT`, because `DNAT` only works in `PREROUTING`, and outgoing packets from an application never traverse `PREROUTING`.

Similarly for `SNAT`, `INPUT` and `POSTROUTING` in case of applications sent to an applications, though I'm not sure about the current status of `SNAT` in `INPUT`, it may be broken and not actually work.

As most masquerading happens in a router forwarding packets, you don't see these kind of applications often.

Comment: It is still unclear for me in what scenario do we need INPUT in OUTPUT in NAT, in firewall table INPUT and OUTPUT are used to block or allow, in NAT, what is their role?

Answer (score 2):

NAT table in the INPUT/OUTPUT chains allow for NAT actions for locally generated traffic inside a Linux router.

If you use NAT in POSTROUTING/PREROUTING, that means both traffic to be forwarded/was forwarded and traffic destinated to the local machine will be NATed

If you only want to NAT traffic for the local machine and keep forwarded traffic intact, you use NAT in INPUT/OUTPUT.

eg: You have a Linux router that also serves as DNS server, for a special reason, you need to change the destination port for your local DNS traffic but don't want to alter routed traffic, then you use NAT INPUT/OUTPUT.